# Neo4J : Get all nodes who are connected to at least K nodes with a path length <= 2

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

With this use case I am finding it to hard with Cypher query. Do I need to write stored procedure for it ?

Comment: Hello! Add a bit more details about your question! Maybe a sample data set and the expected results. Thanks!

Comment: Also please show what you've tried so far, and the general idea you're trying for in your approaches.

Comment: Here is what my graph looks like :

       11

Comment: Here is what my graph looks like :
              11
               |
              12
        /              \
       13            16
     /    \          /      \
    15    14   17    18
----
            1
            |
            4
        / .  | .   \
      8 .   9 .   10
--------
         2
     / .  | .  \
   5 .  6 .  7

Comment: That "graph" doesn't look like a graph. Update your question to provide as much detail as you can.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that will return every node that is connected via paths up to length 2 to at least `k` distinct nodes. `k` is assumed to be passed as a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/).

```
MATCH (n)-[*..2]-(m)
WITH n, COUNT(DISTINCT m) AS ms
WHERE ms > $k
RETURN n, ms;
```

Comment: Doesn't look like its working for me. I am not sure how could I insert my graph or even command here. Its is too big to insert here.

Comment: Update your question to provide as much detail as you can. Right now, there is no information for anyone can help you, if my simple answer does "not work" for you.

Comment: I got the answer from @maxdemarzi and it is as what you suggested with one change and the query is :
MATCH (me)-[:friend*1..2]->(myFriend)
WITH me, count(DISTINCT myFriend) as rC
WHERE rC >=$k
return me
ORDER BY me.uid